# What happens when displaying through Miracast using low resolution device and high resolution external display?

Tags: external-display, screen-resolution, screencast

I am considering purchase of an Android tablet with 1024 x 600 screen resolution and Android 4.4 KitKat. I believe it will support Miracast to cast its display to a Miracast receiver.

The Miracast receiver will be attached to a 1920 × 1080 native resolution TV.

Will Android take full advantage of the full 1920 × 1080 resolution of the Miracast destination device?

What are my options and what would happen on the tablet's screen? What happens on the TV's screen?

**OR: Do I need a tablet / phone with  1920 × 1080 resolution in order to Miracast at full 1920 × 1080 resolution on the external display?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will Android take full advantage of the full 1920 × 1080 resolution of
>   the Miracast destination device?

No. You will end up with a stretched yet aspect-intact mirror of what is on your android.

> What are my options and what would happen on the tablet's screen? What
>   happens on the TV's screen?

Tablet screen remains the same. TV will appear as indicated above. You don't really have options aside from tilting the device to switch between portrait/landscape.

> OR: Do I need a tablet / phone with 1920 × 1080 resolution in order to
>   Miracast at full 1920 × 1080 resolution on the external display?

Nope. If the device supports miracast, it will display on whatever screen the miracast dongle is set up with.